# Network calls javascript race condition?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a dropdown menu with a list of merchants. When a user selects a particular merchant from the dropdown, a network call is made and a JSON is fetched and cached. Thereafter no network calls are made for that particular merchant. On the main page, I have another button. Clicking this button fetches all merchants' data and converts it into JSON.

Now I am confused as to what happens if someone switches the merchant while the button click has triggered a network request for all merchants. Will that create some kind of race condition?

Comment: all depends on the code

Comment: Yes, two network requests in flight at the same time can return in any order. You need to write your code to still do the right thing in all cases